# Function that works for multiple turtles

Tags: python, clone, turtle-graphics

I know this is a very dumb question, but I haven't found any answers.
I've written a function with quite a long definition.

I have to turtles: `p = turtle.Turtle()` and `q = p.clone()`.

```
def scoregraph():
    start = pos()
    color("silver")
    pd()
    rt(90)
    fd(20)
    lt(90)
    fd(200)
    rt(90)
    fd(20)
    rt(90)
    fd(200)
    rt(90)
    fd(60)
    rt(90)
    fd(200)
    lt(90)
    fd(20)
    lt(90)
    fd(200)
    rt(90)
    fd(20)
    color("black")
    fd(6)
    rt(90)
    fd(200)
    rt(90)
    fd(6)
    rt(90)
    fd(200)
    lt(90)
    fd(60)
    lt(90)
    fd(200)
    rt(90)
    fd(60)
    rt(90)
    fd(200)
    rt(90)
    fd(60)
    bk(66)
    rt(90)
    fd(200)
    lt(90)
    fd(126)
    pu()
    goto(start)
    rt(90)
    pd()
```

I try to use the function for the two turtles (`p.scoregraph` and `q.scoregraph`) but it doesn't work.

Is it possible, or do I have to define two separate functions?

Comment: Inlcude your code please. See [ask].

Comment: If Python is anything like java, simply add the method to the turtle; just do p.method() and q.method().

Answer (score 3):

Pass the `Turtle` object to your `scoregraph()` function:

```
def scoregraph(t):
    start = t.pos()
    t.color("silver")
    t.pd()
    t.rt(90)
    t.fd(20)
    # etc
```

Then call like this:

```
p = turtle.Turtle()
q = p.clone()
scoregraph(p)
scoregraph(q)
```

Or, if you'd like a more object oriented style, derive your own class from `Turtle` and provide a `scoregraph()` method. Use `self` to call the turtle methods:

```
class MyTurtle(turtle.Turtle):
    def scoregraph(self):
        self.start = self.pos()
        self.color("silver")
        self.pd()
        self.rt(90)
        self.fd(20)
        # etc

p = MyTurtle()
q = p.clone()
p.scoregraph()
q.scoregraph()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I may or may not have figured it out on may own before I read your reply, or at least the first part, but the second part looks useful. Thank you!